# передать текущее значение элемента массива в span jquery

Tags: php, jquery

проблема в том что в span передается значение последнего найденного элемента, мне необходимо выводить текущее значение,как это сделать? прикрепляю скрины кода ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пример массива obj:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

сам разобрался, два раза присваивал аттрибут price